# PHP: error obtaining data from object with get method

Tags: php, class, oop, object

Here is the class file:

```
<?php
class user{

function _construct($firstName, $lastName, $username, $email, $password){
    $this->firstName    = $firstName;
    $this->lastName     = $lastName;
    $this->username     = $username;
    $this->email        = $email;
    $this->password     = $password;
}

public function getFirstName(){
    return $this->firstName;
}

public function getLastName(){
    return $this->lastName;
}

public function getUsername(){
    return $this->username;
}

public function getEmail(){
    return $this->email;
}

public function getPassword(){
    return $this->password;
}
}
```

Here is the script calling the class file:

```
<?php
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/classes/user.php';
$user1 = new     user('Kyle','Birch','birchk1','theflyinginvalid@gmail.com','195822Kb');
echo $user1->getFirstName() . ' is the first name';
```

Here is the error and display as a result:

```
Notice: Undefined property: user::$firstName in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/classes/user.php on line 13
is the first name
```

Why isn't this calling the get method properly? I want to make sure I use proper coding practices, so even though I could just use public methods/variables without constructs, I prefer to do it properly.

Comment: `_construct` needs 2x **_** so do: **__** `construct`

Comment: As you are not specifically defining the class properties they will get defined as public, so you dont actually need all the getxxx() methods. They can be accessed simply as `$user1->firstName`

Comment: Thank you! That is the stupidest bit of syntax I've seen this side of a goto.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, how do I define the properties as protected? do I do it within the construct?

Comment: @KyleBirch 1) Use an IDE and the constructor will be highlighted with some nice shiny colors, if not then you probably have a typo :) 2) See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php how to initialize your properties

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I just realized that your `_construct` function only has one "_", it needs two underscores: "__" to be syntactically correct

For good OOP practices you need to add the variables as class variables:

```
<?php
class user{

protected $firstName;
protected $lastName;
protected $username;
protected $email;
protected $password;

function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $username, $email, $password){
    $this->firstName    = $firstName;
    $this->lastName     = $lastName;
    $this->username     = $username;
    $this->email        = $email;
    $this->password     = $password;
}

public function getFirstName(){
    return $this->firstName;
}

public function getLastName(){
    return $this->lastName;
}

public function getUsername(){
    return $this->username;
}

public function getEmail(){
    return $this->email;
}

public function getPassword(){
    return $this->password;
}
}
```

Comment: I mention good OOP practices, because since I don't see any setters, it seems that @KyleBirch doesn't want them to be muttable, which is why they are protected and not public.

Comment: `__construct()` is how you define a constructor in PHP

Comment: Read my comment above ^^ again look at your code, read it again, then you know what I mean.

Comment: ahh gotcha! I copy pasted the code form Kyle, which led me to realize his other mistake of only putting one underscore. Good catch ^_^